# Pass Query String Parameter to Newform

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a **DVWP** that is filtered by a query string parameter.  When the user clicks on **Add New Item**, I would like the column that the **DVWP** filters on to auto fill with the same value that the **DVWP** page is currently filering on.  Also, I would like that column to be invisible so that the user cannot change it.  I am not sure how to pass the query string value to `NewForm.aspx` when the user clicks on **Add New Item**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could hide the generated "Add New Item" link and create your own with the query string added to the URL.

Comment: Thank you James.  I couldn't see the link on the page in SPD.  How do I make it invisible?

Comment: Somehwere in the properties for the DVWP I believe.

Comment: What do you do to hide the elements?  I can't seem to get a handle on the "New Item" button in the ribbon.